# Radical editing?

Tags: discussion, editing

I recently answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160258/to-find-the-volume-of-tetrahedron-by-using-all-surfaces-areas) about how the volume of a tetrahedron depends on the surface areas of the faces.  I like the content of this question a lot, but unfortunately the original wording was terrible.  I have cleaned it up a bit, but I'm curious how much editing is permissible.

For example, would it be out of line to simply replace the text of the question with the following?

> Is there a formula for the volume of a tetrahedron as a function of the areas $S_1$, $S_2,$ $S_3$, $S_4$ of the four faces?

This would certainly be helpful for anyone who arrives at the question via a Google search, but it seems to lose some of the content of the original question.

Comment: Related: [How much editing is too much?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/how-much-editing-is-too-much)

Answer (score 18):

What I have sometimes done when I wanted to answer a badly written question is, I have started my answer with, "I think the question you are trying to ask is ...," after which I proceed to answer the question in the formulation I've just given to it. If I'm wrong, OP can just say, no, that wasn't the question, and no harm is done. In terms of web searches, it shouldn't make too much difference whether the better-written question is at the top of the page or in my answer.